# Error 401 with cloud scheduler while passing Dataflow template as URL via POST request

Tags: python-3.x, post, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler, google-dataflow

I have created a custom template for Dataflow Batch Jobs. Now I need to run every 5 minutes using cloud scheduler.
The template is stored in cloud storage. But I'm getting 401 error, whenever I pass the URI of template in my POST request from scheduler

```
        URI - "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/project-id/locations/region/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://my_bucket/templates/mytemplate
```

I'm not sure what the body should contain

Error:

```
     jsonPayload: {
     targetType: "HTTP"
     @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished"
     status: "UNAUTHENTICATED"
     url: "https://storage.cloud.google.com/my_bucket/templates/mydemotemp"
     jobName: "projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/jobs/finaljob"
     }
     httpRequest: {
     status: 401
```

Can anyone please help as how to go about it. Since I'm new to GCP

Comment: How did you have configured your Cloud Scheduler? Did you add authentication information?

Answer (score 1):

It could happen when the service account that you used for Cloud scheduler don't have permission to access to bucket.

You can use your service account for cloud scheduler authentication.

Set service account like below, Or refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth#creating_a_scheduler_job_with_authentication) to get detailed guide.

[image]

Before setting your cloud scheduler, grant your service account a role like "Storage Object view" or higher level.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) to check GCS roles that required for bucket access.

Comment: I have added the service account and authetication. I'm able to access for GET also. But for POST it throwing an error

Comment: It means your service account have permission that can view list of your bucket's object, but don't have one that can write object to bucket. Have you checked service account's permission granted properly?

Comment: @anaghas Try setting up as owner the owner role at first, then downgrade it to the proper role you want it to have, this will force the roles to be re-applied.

Comment: @kallusis369 then how is GET working and not POST? Its working fine with GET

Comment: @Rafael Lemos could you explain how to do the same?